# TypeError while running scons tests for Galsim installation on macOS 10.12 with anaconda

Tags: scons, galsim

I am trying to install Galsim by following the instructions on https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/blob/master/INSTALL.md#0-overall-summary but keep getting the following typeerror when I reach the `scons tests` portion.

```
    Starting python tests...
    scons: *** [tests/tests.log] TypeError : write() argument must be str, not bytes
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/lorena/anaconda3/lib/scons-3.0.0/SCons/Action.py", line 1197, in execute
    result = self.execfunction(target=target, source=rsources, env=env)
    File "/Users/lorena/git/GalSim/tests/SConscript", line 81, in run_tests
    sys.stdout.write(buf)
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
    scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I'm using python 3.6.

Comment: Please try SCons 3.0.1 and report back.

Comment: Does it run o.k. with python 2.7.x?

Comment: @bdbaddog, I tried SCons 3.0.1 and still have the same problem.

Comment: What about running with python 2.7.x?

Comment: @bdbaddog, Thanks for your help. I get the error above whenever I try to run scons tests, yet Galsim seems to have installed fine despite this issue.

Comment: You still didn't answer if you get this error with python 2.7.x?